# Clearing Widget ID#

Tags: app-widgets

I am trying to solve a problem with an old version of Desktop Visualizer. It seems that whenever I make a clean install on another device, the first widget ID# is randomly set to some value (1, 5, 3, whatever).

My issue is that I have written a pair of Tasker apps which rely on a known value for a widget ID#. The apps should be portable but each installation of Desktop Visualizer starts at some unpredictable widget ID#.

I've tried copying over databases and xml settings files from one install to another to no avail. I've backed up an install from one device and restored it to another. The widgets don't survive the transfer (likely because they are also part of the launcher database).

There is unfortunately no way to make the widget ID# a variable in the Tasker app. That would be ideal. Then the user could simply add that information. Or, if the ID# were "sussable", the app might be able to track it down itself. Unfortunately all the information on widgets in Desktop Visualizer appears to be either encrypted or deliberately obfuscated.

Is there somewhere else in the OS where this kind of information is stored? Maybe something that needs resetting?